# How to stop my loop from ending at the end of i

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, pycharm

The prompt is:

> Using PyCharm, under lab8, under Directory exercise, create a Python file called
> more_loops.py. Write a function, `nbrs_greater` that accepts 2 integer lists as parameters,
> and returns a list of integers that indicates how many integers in the second list are greater than each integer in the first list. For example: `nbrs_greater([3, 4, 1, 2, 7], [10, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3])` returns `[3, 2, 5, 4, 1]`

And my code is working sometimes, but when I enter:

```
nbrs_greater([20, 5, 1, 6], [1, 4, 8, 12, 16])
```

It won't continue past `6` and returns `[0, 3, 4]` instead of `[0, 3, 4, 3]` because there are three values for which 6 is greater than in list 2.

Here is my original code--------

```
def nbrs_greater(list_1, list_2):
    final_list = []
    list_count = []
    list_greater = []
    number_of_greater = 0
    for i in list_1:
        for j in list_2:
            if i < j:
                list_greater.append(i)
                number_of_greater += 1
            if i > max(list_2):
                list_count.append(0)
    for k in list_greater:
        count_list_var = list_greater.count(k)
        list_count.append(count_list_var)
    for h in list_count:
        if h not in final_list:
            final_list.append(h)
    if len(final_list) == 0:
        final_list.append(0)
    return final_list


print(nbrs_greater([20, 5, 1, 6], [1, 4, 8, 12, 16]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need a list of each number that's greater in order to get the count. You can use the `sum()` function to get a count.

```
def nbrs_greater(list_1, list_2):
    final_list = []
    for i in list_1:
        greater_count = sum(j > i for j in list_2)
        final_list.append(greater_count)
    return final_list
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps!

Answer (score 0):

At here `if h not in final_list:` you mean `final_list` has  not same num,so it won't apear two '3'.The  different count numbers can be ok.